# How to read local client side text files, without using any html input/search elements

Tags: javascript, game-engine

The purpose, game programming, as you may have guessed, why else right?
How is it actually possible to read in values from a text file, so that those values can be then on wards used in the game? I have searched for hours on this topic.

example: each text file line token, will be read and passed as the different arguments into the constructor of each object during its instantiation via for loop. A common practice. Its Too expensive to store that much data at any given time in an array I would suspect.

In java this is dead simple using the Scanner object.

Any suggestions are appreciated thanks. I guess all I am asking is, is it even possible?

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Comment: If you cant store that much data at any given time in an array i doubt the instantiated objects will take less memory.

Answer (score 0):

As [Roland Starke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844401/how-to-read-local-client-side-text-files-without-using-any-html-input-search-el/36845474#comment61259021_36844401) said, the array will probably take up less memory than the objects you construct from it... So it is perfectly fine to have all the information in a JSON file for instance, which you load from your server.

If you want to avoid transfering all the data every time, you would need to use the right [caching headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) so that the data can be cached by the browser.